# replace data in array with str_replace function

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

i have an array named `$data`

```
$data = array(
                    'word1'=>'Šššš',
                    'word2'=>'Zzzzžzzž',
                    'word3'=>'Āāāa'
                    );
```

what i want to do is to create new array with the same keys but with different values, so my new array would look like this:

```
$newdata = array(
                    'word1'=>'Ssss',
                    'word2'=>'Zzzzzzzz',
                    'word3'=>'Aaaa'
                    );
```

all i want to do is to replace letters with diacritical mark  to normal letter, i have searched for php  functions and i have understood that i could use `str_replace` function like this:

```
$search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
$replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Ž', ž);
str_replace($search, $replace, $data);
```

but how can i `loop` through `array` checking and replacing values without touching `keys`?
or i cannot do that?(all data have to be be checked)

Comment: To transliterate a string like that, look into iconv and/or http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php rather than re-inventing the ICU library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
 $data = array(
    'word1'=>'Šššš',
    'word2'=>'Zzzzžzzž',
    'word3'=>'Āāāa'
);

$search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
$replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Ž', 'ž');
$data2 = array();
foreach($data as $k =>$v){
    $data2[$k] = str_replace($search, $replace, $data[$k]);
}
print_r($data2);
```

you can change the line inside foreach by this:

```
$data2[$k] = str_replace($search, $replace, $v);
```

<kbd>[demo](https://eval.in/148154)</kbd>

Comment: check out the demo @Xatenev

Comment: Ah i see, why is it acting like this? Normally [] is creating a new element. In my thoughts - you would override $data2['KEY'] with each element again?

Comment: Not from me .. anyways.. Can you give an answer on my question?^^

Comment: it is new array `$data2`

Comment: `str_replace()` does not require a loop.  It will happily traverse a 1d array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function splReplace($string)
{
    $search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
    $replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Ž', ž);
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}

$data = array(
                'word1'=>'Šššš',
                'word2'=>'Zzzzžzzž',
                'word3'=>'Āāāa'
                );

$data = array_map('splReplace',$data)   ;
```

Comment: `str_replace()` does not require a loop.  It will happily traverse a 1d array.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter, `$subject` for the `str_replace` function can be an array. So no need to loop through the values yourself. Tested on php 5.5, it'll keep your keys and values intact

```
$search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
$replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Z', 'z');

$data = array(
            'word1'=>'Šššš',
            'word2'=>'Zzzzžzzž',
            'word3'=>'Āāāa'
);

$data = str_replace($search, $replace, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

with a simple foreach

```
<?php
$search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
$replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Ž', ž);
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = str_replace($search, $replace, $data[$key]);
}
?>
```

Comment: `str_replace()` does not require a loop.  It will happily traverse a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

A foreach works well

```
    $data = array(
                'word1'=>'Šššš',
                'word2'=>'Zzzzžzzž',
                'word3'=>'Āāāa'
                );

    $search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š', 'Ž', 'ž');
    $replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's', 'Ž', ž);      

    foreach($data as $k => $v) { // for each element in $data
        $data[$k] = str_replace($search, $replace, $v); // do replacement and assign back to the array.
    }

    print "<pre>"; print_r($data); print "</pre>"; // print formatted array
```

Comment: `str_replace()` does not require a loop.  It will happily traverse a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can use a foreach with a [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
$search  = array('Ā', 'ā', 'Š', 'š');
$replace = array('A', 'a', 'S', 's');
foreach ($data as &$word) {
    $word = str_replace($search, $replace, $word);
}
```

However, an easier way would to use a foreach with [normalizer_normalize](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php):

```
foreach ($data as &$word) {
    $word = normalizer_normalize($word);
}
```

or using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$data = array_map('normalizer_normalize', $data);
```

Please note that [normalizer_normalize](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) was added to the core in PHP 5.3, but in most linux distributions it isn't active by default.

You can also try out [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)():

```
foreach ($data as &$word) {
    $word = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $word);
}
```

Comment: `str_replace()` does not require a loop.  It will happily traverse a 1d array.